# ¿Cómo hacer un histograma por grupo?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, rstudio, dataset

¿Cómo hacer un histograma por grupo?

Estoy usando R studio. Lo que pasa es que tengo un dataset en el cual tengo 1000k datos. Tengo todos columas llamadas CLASIFICACION_FINAL y EDAD. En la columna de CLASIFICACION_FINAL hay datos que van del 1 al 7. En esta columna decimos que aquellos que tienen 1, 2 o 3, están contagiados de SARS_COVID, mientras que en los que tienen 4, 5,6 y 7 son los que están sanos. Yo necesito hacer un histograma de las edades de los que están contagiados y para esto tengo entendido que debo hacer un grupo para ver las edades que coinciden con 1, 2 y 3 de la columna CLASIFICACION_FINAL y esas edades serán de las personas contagiadas y, a partir de ahí necesito hacer el histograma pero no encuentro la manera de crear el grupo u obtener esto.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

Tengo el sigueinte codigo

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

#- Mas informacion sobre el dataset utilizado: https://datos.gob.mx/busca/dataset/informacion-referente-a-casos-covid-19-en-mexico





#1) Descarga el csv de los datos del COVID http://datosabiertos.salud.gob.mx/gobmx/salud/datos_abiertos/datos_abiertos_covid19.zip,
# importa los datos en R
# RECOMENDACION: usar read_csv

covid_dataset <- read_csv("Desktop/Curso en R/Ejemplos/covid_dataset.csv")
View(covid_dataset)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#2) Extrae una muestra aleatoria de 100k registros y asignala en una nueva variable. A partir de ahora trabaja con este dataset
# HINT: usar funcion sample_n de dplyr

muestra <- sample_n(covid_dataset, 100000)

#Con la funcion sample_n lo que nos da es una sintaxis sample_n(x,n) donde tenemos que
#x sera nuestro dataset de donde queremos extraer la muestra y n es el tamaño de la muestra
#que deseamos

nrow(muestra)

#con esta funcion podemos corroborar que hemos extraido una muestra de 100K


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#3)Haz un resumen estadistico del dataset y tambien muestra los tipos de datos por columna

summary(muestra)

#La funcion summary es la que nos da el resumen estadistico 

map(muestra, class)

#La funcion map() nos otorga el tipo de dato por columnas y podemos ver que hay
#mas tipo de datos numeric.

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#4)Filtra los renglones que dieron positivo para SARS-COVID y calcula el numero de registros
## Los casos positivos son aquellos que en la columna CLASIFICACION_FINAL tienen 1, 2 o 3


#Para filtrar los renglones, haremos uso del operador PIPE y de la funcion select de dplyr
#Esto nos ayudara a seleccionar la columna y poder filtrar los renglones en los cuales
#la columna CLASIFICACION_FINAL es 1, 2 o 3, es decir, los resultados positivos a SARS-COVID



muestra %>% select(CLASIFICACION_FINAL) %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 1) 

# Aqui me filtra los renglones para los cuales la columna CLASIFICACION_FINAL tiene un 1

muestra %>% select(CLASIFICACION_FINAL) %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 2)

# Aqui me filtra los renglones para los cuales la columna CLASIFICACION_FINAL tiene un 2

muestra %>% select(CLASIFICACION_FINAL) %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 3)

# Aqui me filtra los renglones para los cuales la columna CLASIFICACION_FINAL tiene un 3



#Los hago por separado para tener una mejor visión de los registros




#Ahora que si queremos obtenerlos de manera conjunta simplemente hacemos lo siguiente

muestra %>% select(CLASIFICACION_FINAL) %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL <= 3)

#Esto nos otorga los renglones menores o iguales que 3, que es lo mismo a danors los
#renglones en que la columna CLASIFICACION_FINAL tiene 1, 2 o 3


#Ahora, si queremos el numero de registros, haciendolo por separado, simplemente agregamos
#otro operador PIPE en el cual agregaremos la funcion nrow() para que me de el numero de
#renglones por cada registro.

muestra %>% select(CLASIFICACION_FINAL) %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 1) %>% nrow()

#Nos da un resultado de 1471

muestra %>% select(CLASIFICACION_FINAL) %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 2) %>% nrow()

#Nos da un resultado de 46

muestra %>% select(CLASIFICACION_FINAL) %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 3) %>% nrow()

#Nos da un resultado de 37703


#Si sumamos los 3 resultados, tenemos que el numero total de registros es

1471+46+37703

#Lo que nos da 39220


#Pero se puede simplificar haciendolo de manera directa como sigue 

muestra %>% select(CLASIFICACION_FINAL) %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL <= 3) %>% nrow()

#Y notamos que obtenemos el mismo resultado que el codigo anterior 

#En conclusion, tenemos un total de 39220 casos positivos de SARS-COVID
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#5)Cuenta el numero de registros nulos por columna (HINT: Usar sapply o map, e is.na)


apply(muestra, MARGIN = 2, function(x)sum(is.na(x)))

#Esto nos muestra el numero de NA's por columna. Nos damos cuenta que la unica columna
#que tiene NA's es la de FECHA_DEF con un total de 95044, esto nos dice que de los
#100K datos, solo se conocen aproximadamente 5k datos para FECHA_DEF.



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#6)
##a)Calcular la media de edades de los contagiados de covid
##b)Realiza un Histograma de las edades de los contagiados 
##c)Realiza una grafica de densidad de edades de los contagiados


muestra %>%
  group_by(CLASIFICACION_FINAL <= 3 ) %>%
  summarise(promedio = mean(EDAD))


#Entonces el promedio total de contagiados es 43.9


#Ahora hacemos un histograma de las edades de los contagiados

muestra %>% group_by(CLASIFICACION_FINAL <=3, EDAD) %>% summarise(conteo = n())
```

Es en la última parte donde tengo dudas. Quiero hallar el promedio de las edades de las personas contagiadas, use el codigo que puse ahí usango `group_by` pero no se si eso sea correcto. Y mi duda ya son con las otras dos cuestiones de #6 que es donde quiero saber lo de los histogramas y como poder gra

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta es sobre este código `muestra %>% group_by(CLASIFICACION_FINAL <= 3 ) %>% summarise(promedio = mean(EDAD))`? No veo nada mal, vas a terminar con un grupo `TRUE` y otro `FALSE` cada uno con el promedio de edad que le corresponde a contagiados y no contagiados. ¿Cuál es tu duda?

Comment: ¿Cuándo hablas de un histograma, estás hablando del gráfico? ¿Qué motor gráfico quieres usar, base, ggplot, lattice, otro?